# Adding a logo image beside text in div using html and css

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a top bar with just a name or an Example Text at the left-hand side while having a group logo (png image) aligned at the right-hand side. But the text and the image are in same division and the image and text shall be in same line what I have right now is

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="topBar">
            <p class="topBar-Text">Example Text</p>
            <img class="groupIcon" src="resources/groupIcon.png" width="100" height="100">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

in html and

```css
.topBar {

    background-color: seashell;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;

}

.topBar-Text {

    margin-left: 30px;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;

}

.groupIcon {

    float: right;

}
```

In CSS but the `float: right;` removes the image from division and isn't in the same line as text but does align the image at right
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcqPP.png)
So how can I make it so the image is aligned at right, inside the division, and in the same line as text [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrtqY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox in the `topBar` class.

```
.topBar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```